# Converting String to Int without converting the variable itself

Tags: c#

I want to have a string, which I then want to pass to 2 variables.
One is Int, the other is string.

So normally I could do:

```
string1 = string2;
int1 = Convert.ToInt32(string2);
```

But I wonder if it's possible to do it in another approach,
I want to convert the string to Int just as it reaches the int1 variable; O don't want to convert the actually string2 to Int.

So basically like the topic says:

```
string1 = int1(convert to int) = string2
```

I am not sure if this is possible at all, hopefully it is.

Comment: So you want to convert `string2` to an integer… without converting it? Or are you looking for a [`Tuple<string, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx)? Do you want to define a class that itself defines widening conversions to `string` and `int`?

Comment: ...and assign two things of two different types to the same variable at once? that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Think of it like this, string -> int -> string . I convert it to int, then back again (though i actually just want to convert to a temp int)

Comment: You can’t do that, because of types. That’s what they’re for. Strings are not integers.

Comment: So i can only make 1 conversion per " = " section?

Comment: Why would you convert it to a temp int? I'm confused as to what the string1 is for, but you could do string -> string -> int: `int1 = Convert.ToInt32(string1 = string2);`

Comment: Instead of telling how you think you need to achieve your aim, perhaps you could tell us what your aim is.  What you're suggesting makes little sense so tell us what you're trying to achieve and then we'll tell you how to achieve it.

Comment: @itsme86 , That was what i was looking for. Giving both strings the same value, and at the same time give that value to an int type!

Comment: @Zerowalker It might be fun just for giggles, but I would never do that in production code. The result is too obscure for the maintenance cycle.

Comment: @itsme86 , It's just for saving some space for my application as i am wasting lines at a place. Not really for anything "serious", for readability i wouldn't use it;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic.

```
MagicInt x = 123;
string s = x;
int i = x;
Console.WriteLine("s is " + s);
Console.WriteLine("i is " + i);


public struct MagicInt
{
    public MagicInt(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    public MagicInt(string value)
    {
        _value = int.Parse(value);
    }

    int _value;

    public static implicit operator int(MagicInt value)
    {
        return value._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MagicInt value)
    {
        return value._value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator MagicInt(int value)
    {
        return new MagicInt(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator MagicInt(string value)
    {
        return new MagicInt(value);
    }

}
```